# ASP.Net Core MVC Accessing a ViewModel From a View for a Select control

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, select, viewmodel

I would first like to take I am a novice at this, my background is asp web forms and I am trying to update my skill set to the latest development language.

I have a view which needs to access multiple modules so I created a viewmodel and pass that to the view. My problem is when I try to access a list from the view model to populate a select (dropdown). I keep getting an error. Below is my viewmodel: -

```cs
    public class CustomerDetailsViewModel
    {
        public Customer customer { get; set; }    
        public IEnumerable<Lookups> titles { get; set; }
        public List<Lookups> ePCs { get; set; }
        public List<Lookups> jobStages { get; set; }
    }
```

Below is my code for the select control. Where I try to access the titles list I get an error.

```html
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="customer.Title_Id" class="col-sm-2 col-md-4 col-form-label">Title</label>
            <select app-for="Title_Id" asp-items="@(new SelectList(titles,"PK_Id","Description"))"></select>
        </div>
```

Comment: What does the error message say? And you cannot access properties directly, you have to access them through the `Model` property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have created a view model, I assume your view has the `@model` directive:

```
@model CustomerDetailsViewModel
```

When you pass the view model from the controller to the view, it is accessible in the view through the `Model` property.
The `asp-for` tag helper does not need the `Model` property, it is implicit. On the other hand, `asp-items` does not work that way, it needs the `Model` prefix:

```
<select asp-for="customer.Title_Id" 
        asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.titles,"PK_Id","Description"))">
</select>
```

Also, since all your view model properties are `public`, the naming convention is to use `PascalCase` names:

```
 public class CustomerDetailsViewModel
 {
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }    
        public IEnumerable<Lookups> Titles { get; set; }
        public List<Lookups> EPCs { get; set; }
        public List<Lookups> JobStages { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you know how to bootstrap style the select control? Mine looks a bit flat.

Comment: @user1633508 You're welcome. Yes, use `<select class="form-control">`. You can also use `custom-select`. More on it [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#form-controls). For more flexible styling, try the [bootstrap-select](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/) plugin

Comment: Thank you again, I tried to use the bootstrap selectpicker class but it does not do anything. I have in my layout file a reference to the bootstrap css so not sure what I am missing.

Comment: I've added the plugin files and the select control looks styled now but I cannot select from the list, it does not drop down. Any ideas please?

Comment: @user1633508 It seems like the list is not populated. Was it working before using the plugin?

Comment: I found the problem. I have tried to download the popper.min.js file but it showed code so I paste it into a text file. I changed to a CDN path and it works. For my development environment I try to use local files. Do you know where I can download the popper.min.js file please?